# Customize the Header of MIAW: No MODULE named markup://lightningsnapin:eventStore found

Tags: lightning-web-components, header, embedded-services, messaging-for-web

### I have been facing the error: "No MODULE named markup://lightningsnapin:eventStore found" when using the code of Customize the Header of Messaging for Web Channel of Salesforce with the link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-web/guide/customize-header.html
Please help me check

### js.file:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import { dispatchMessagingEvent, assignMessagingEventHandler, MESSAGING_EVENT } from "lightningsnapin/eventStore";

const SLDS_MENU_SELECTOR = "slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click";

export default class ChatHeader extends LightningElement {
/**
 * Deployment configuration data.
* @type {Object}
*/
@api configuration = {};

/**
 * The status of the conversation. Valid values:
* - NOT_STARTED
* - OPEN
* - CLOSED
* @type {ConversationStatus}
*/
@api conversationStatus;

/**
 * Class name for header menu.
* @type {String}
*/
menuClass = SLDS_MENU_SELECTOR;

/**
 * Array to store bot options menu.
* @type {Array}
*/
chatbotOptionsMenu = [];

/**
 * Whether the use is authenticated.
* AuthMode can have the following values:
* - Auth: user is in verified, which corresponds to the authenticated user mode.
* - UnAuth: user is in unverified,  which corresponds to the guest user mode.
*/
get isAuthenticatedContext() {
    return this.configuration.embeddedServiceMessagingChannel.authMode === "Auth";
}

/**
 * Whether to show the back button.
* @type {Boolean}
*/
showBackButton = false;

/**
 * Whether to show the header menu button.
* @returns {Boolean}
*/
get showMenuButton() {
    return this.conversationStatus === "OPEN";
}

/**
 * Whether to show the header menu.
* @type {Boolean}
*/
_showMenu = false;
get showMenu() {
    return this._showMenu;
}
set showMenu(shouldShow) {
    this.menuClass = SLDS_MENU_SELECTOR + (shouldShow ? " slds-is-open" : "");
    this._showMenu = shouldShow;
}

/**
 * Whether to show the close button.
* @returns {Boolean}
*/
get showCloseButton() {
    return this.conversationStatus !== "OPEN";
}

/**
 * Handle back button click.
*/
onBackButtonClick() {
    dispatchMessagingEvent(MESSAGING_EVENT.BACK_BUTTON_CLICK, {});
}

/**
 * Handle menu button click.
*/
onMenuButtonClick() {
    this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
}

/**
 * Handle minimize button click.
*/
onMinimizeButtonClick() {
    dispatchMessagingEvent(MESSAGING_EVENT.MINIMIZE_BUTTON_CLICK, {});
}

/**
 * Handle close button click.
*/
onCloseButtonClick() {
    dispatchMessagingEvent(MESSAGING_EVENT.CLOSE_CONTAINER, {});
}

/**
 * Handle end conversation button click.
*/
onMenuOptionClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    dispatchMessagingEvent(MESSAGING_EVENT.MENU_ITEM_SELECTED, {
        selectedOption: this.chatbotOptionsMenu.find(option => option.optionIdentifier === event.target.getAttribute("value"))
    });

    this.showMenu = false;
}

/**
 * Handle end conversation button click.
*/
onEndConversationClick() {
    dispatchMessagingEvent(MESSAGING_EVENT.CLOSE_CONVERSATION, {});

    this.showMenu = false;
}

connectedCallback() {
    assignMessagingEventHandler(MESSAGING_EVENT.PARTICIPANT_JOINED, (data) => {
        console.log(`Participant joined`);

        if (data.options && Array.isArray(data.options)) {
            data.options.forEach((participantOption) => {
                this.chatbotOptionsMenu.push(participantOption);
            });
        }
    });

    assignMessagingEventHandler(MESSAGING_EVENT.PARTICIPANT_LEFT, (data) => {
        console.log(`Participant left`);

        this.chatbotOptionsMenu = [];
    });

    assignMessagingEventHandler(MESSAGING_EVENT.UPDATE_HEADER_TEXT, (data) => {
        console.log(`Update header text: ${data.text}`);
    });

    assignMessagingEventHandler(MESSAGING_EVENT.TOGGLE_BACK_BUTTON, (data) => {
        console.log(`Toggle back button visibility.`);

        this.showBackButton = !this.showBackButton;
    });
}
}
```

---

xml.file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>60.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningSnapin__MessagingHeader</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

---

html.file:

```
<template>
    <!-- Back button -->
    <template if:true={showBackButton}>
        <button class="headerButton backButton" onclick={onBackButtonClick}>
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:back" variant="inverse" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
        </button>
    </template>

    <!-- Header menu -->
    <section class={menuClass}>
        <template if:true={showMenuButton}>
            <!-- Menu button -->
            <button class="headerButton menuButton" onclick={onMenuButtonClick}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:threedots_vertical" variant="inverse" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
            </button>
        </template>

        <!-- Menu options-->
        <section class="optionsMenu slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_left slds-nubbin_top-left">
            <ul class="slds-dropdown__list">
                <!-- Bot menu options -->
                <template for:each={chatbotOptionsMenu} for:item="option">
                    <li class="slds-dropdown__item" key={option.optionIdentifier}>
                        <button class="chatbotMenuOption"
                                value={option.optionIdentifier}
                                onclick={onMenuOptionClick}>
                            <span value={option.optionIdentifier}>{option.title}</span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </template>

                <!-- End conversation option -->
                <template if:false={isAuthenticatedContext}>
                    <li class="slds-dropdown__item">
                        <button class="chatbotMenuOption"
                                onclick={onEndConversationClick}>
                            <span class="slds-text-color_error">End Conversation</span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </section>

    <!-- Header logo -->
    <!-- Replace this with your logo file. -->
    <img src="/path/to/logo.png" alt="My Logo"/>

    <!-- Header text -->
    <h2>Custom Header</h2>

    <!-- Minimize button -->
    <button class="headerButton minimizeButton" onclick={onMinimizeButtonClick}>
        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:chevrondown" variant="inverse" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
    </button>

    <!-- Close button -->
    <template if:true={showCloseButton}>
        <button class="headerButton closeButton" onclick={onCloseButtonClick}>
            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" variant="inverse" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
        </button>
    </template>
</template>
```

---

css.file:

```
:host {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 14px;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}

img {
    margin-right: 4px;
    max-height: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: initial;
    align-self: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: white;
}

.headerButton {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 32px;
    min-height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    min-width: 32px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.headerButton:hover:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: .2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.headerButton.menuButton:hover:before {
    top: 0;
}

.headerButton.closeButton:hover:before {
    right: 14px;
}

lightning-icon {
    fill: white;
}

.optionsMenu {
    width: 100vw;
    left: -0.9rem;
}

.optionsMenu > .slds-dropdown__list {
    max-height: 20rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.slds-nubbin_top-left:before,
.slds-nubbin_top-left:after {
    left: 2rem;
    top: -0.5rem;
}

.slds-dropdown {
    max-width: 30rem;
}

.slds-dropdown__item > button {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.slds-dropdown__item > button:focus,
.slds-dropdown__item > button:hover {
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.slds-dropdown__list > .slds-dropdown__item:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: #e2e2e2 1px solid;
}

.slds-dropdown__item .slds-truncate:not(.closeConversation) {
    color: #005290;
}
```

Comment: Please help me :<